# Waiting for OK button to be clicked in simplemodal modal.alert()

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I am using simplemodal to display my dailog boxes...

I have the following code for handling json post response:
The data.message for a success contains the Thank You for joining text..

```
 function(data){
          if(data.result=='success'){
            $.modal.alert(data.message,{modal:true});
            window.location.href='login.cfm';
          }else{
              $.modal.alert(data.message);
          }
      }
```

My problem is that the modal alert never shows up(or displays too fast to see) and the window.location processes.

How do I code it so the window.location waits for the OK button to be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I think [link](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation) help you.

You are not waiting for response from dialog box, you are showing dialog box and then redirecting the page. so page redirecting.

Comment: Thanks for the information...I read the link.. that is for a jquery modal window.  Simplemodal is a "wrapper" around jquery.  I believe there is something different I need to do... specific to simplemodal.

Comment: $(function() {
$( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
resizable: false,
height:140,
modal: true,
buttons: {
"Delete all items": function() {
$( this ).dialog( "close" );
},
Cancel: function() {
$( this ).dialog( "close" );
}
}
});
});

Comment: I tried that code in place of the $modal.alert(data.message);  It did not display anything.

Comment: give me the url if u still facing the problem